# What is すまして in this sentence?

Tags: reading-comprehension

「さっき食べたばかりだろう。お腹を壊すよ」

「うるせえ。夏の間に食っておかなきゃ」

ばりばりとアイスの袋を破りながら、恭はすまして言った。

「八月なんてあっという間に終わっちまうんだから」

八月が終われば、九月がやってくる。すぐに彼岸になる。

I understand the sentence as a whole, however I'm stuck in this particular nuance here

> ばりばりとアイスの袋を破りながら、恭はすまして言った。

As he rips  the icecream's bag, Kyou said this. My first guess would be akin to "unconcerned"?

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. It is the te-form of [すます](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%99%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99/#jn-119957) meaning:

> ４
> ㋐そのようなことは**自分に関係ないという顔をする**。平然と構える。平気でいる。「—・した顔で人を笑わせる」

So it means *unconcerned* (here about the possibility of getting stomachache).